# Extract Content from Atom Feeds

Tags: google-apps-script

Am trying to extract "/rss/channel/item/title" and "/rss/channel/item/description" from the Wordsmith XML Feed. However I never figured out to extract them from the feed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function getWotd(){
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://wordsmith.org/awad/rss1.xml").getContentText();

  var parsedResponse = Xml.parse(response, false);


  Logger.log(parsedResponse);  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to get the root element of the document (rss) using `getElement()` and then crawl down the DOM from there.

```
  var title = parsedResponse.getElement()
      .getElement('channel')
      .getElement('item')
      .getElement('title')
      .getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your piece of code

```
var text = parsedResponse.getElement().getElement('rss').getElement('channel')
           .getElement('item').getElement('title').getText();
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot call method "getElement" of null. (line 11)